# Windows Server 2008 R2 Shared Folders MMC: open mode "no access"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

Can somebody explain what does "no access" open mode mean in Open Files node of Shared Folders MMC snap-in in Windows Server 2008 R2?
Title of column "Open Mode" and value "no access" looking a bit controversial...

Comment: Looks like this is somehow similar to the red down arrow icon in RDS Manager console next to Active session - it's conunterintuitive and doesn't look right, but when I tried to find why it is so or why does it mean the only mention I found was something like "this is a known issue which will be fixed in future versions" on some forgotten blog... It was years ago but looks like not only nobody fixed it but also nobody took an effort to provide a clear expalnation about it.